# reload/ redirect after schedule Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, scheduled-tasks

Is there a possibility to reload/ redirect after a schedule is run in laravel?

I already tried it with the -> after() method on the schedule, but I can't get it to work.

```
$schedule->command('update:request')
            ->everyFiveMinutes()
            ->withoutOverlapping()
            ->after(function (){
                return redirect('/');
            });
```

Comment: Redirect what ? Schedule commands are run by console/background process (like cron), there is no client/user to redirect to a page. Even if technically the redirection works, it will not show on your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command-side redirection is not possible. With Event listener, you can take action after the command finishes working. However, since Command is not linked to a page, redirection cannot be performed.